# How much gold can I receive for each chest/skull/commodity?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

In Sea of Thieves, there are different types of chests, skulls, and commodities (pigs, chickens, gun powder barrels).  When I sold my Castaway Chest to the Gold Hoarder faction, I received varying amounts.  They were between 80 - 120 (roughly) gold each. I know that I received close to 800 gold for my Captain's Chest that I found the other day.

My gun powder barrel that I sold to the Merchant's faction went for about 180 gold, and my Black Plumed Chicken was about 120 gold.  I also had a Disgraced Skull that sold for about 280 to the Order of the Souls.

It seems that the game chooses a random number between a certain range of values for each item, depending on how rare it is.  So, what is the range of gold that I can receive from each type of chest, skull, and commodity?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got just over 1000 the other day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've seen either in-game or by reading about the game on The Internet. Some data is missing; I'll edit this answer as I learn more.

## Chests

```
Name                             Sale Price 
-------------------------   ---------------
Captain's Chest              ~600-1020 gold
Castaway's Chest               ~70-130 gold
Chest of a Thousand Grogs*   ~840-1470 gold   
Chest of Sorrow**            ~800-1540 gold
Marauder's Chest              ~300-520 gold
Seafarer's Chest              ~140-260 gold
Stronghold Chest            ~1420-3340 gold

* causes carrier to be drunk
** cries occasionally and fills ships with water
```

## Commodities

```
Name                    Sale Price   Sale Price (quest)
----------------   ---------------   ------------------
Chicken                                       
    Black
    Gold            
    Red
    White           
Exotic Silks         ~570-920 gold
Exquisite Spices   ~1240-1860 gold
Fine Sugar           ~140-230 gold
Gunpowder Barrel      ~80-180 gold
Pig     
    Black
    Gold
    Pink
    Pink & Black                  
Rare Tea             ~260-560 gold
Snake                                         
    Black
    Blue
    Red
    Yellow
```

## Skulls

```
Name                    Sale Price
----------------   ---------------
Disgraced Skull      ~190-350 gold
Foul Skull           ~100-170 gold
Hateful Skull        ~401-690 gold
Villainous Skull    ~910-1350 gold
Stronghold Skull   ~2310-3950 gold
```

## Miscellaneous

```
Name                Sale Price       Faction
----------------   ---------------   ---------------
Silver Chalice     ~250 gold         Gold Hoarders
```

## Reference

- [Treasure Chest](https://seaofthieves.gamepedia.com/Treasure_Chest)
- [Rare Tea Crate](https://seaofthieves.gamepedia.com/Rare_Tea_Crate)
- [Bounty Skulls](https://seaofthieves.gamepedia.com/Bounty_Skulls)
- [Quick Guide to Merchant Quests](https://www.reddit.com/r/Seaofthieves/comments/837qzs/quick_guide_to_merchant_quests/)
- [Sea of Thieves Loot Values (spreadsheet)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LoHGbNR-stSqqn264qIYC55VWoOy8aOEHoEK8Upv7ys/edit#gid=1978170999)

Comment: Good start, but I would like to know the ranges.  I saw these Wiki pages before, but they only seem to give the averages.

Comment: So far I can say that the ranges are quite large for some of the better items.  For example, I had 2 Chests of Sorrows.  One sold for around 800, while the other was 1400.  A 600 difference is quite significant.

Comment: @TimmyJim I found a spreadsheet where users are submitting sale prices for various commodities. I've edited my answer to include ranges based on current values, rounded to the nearest 10 gold. I expect the spreadsheet will help us get closer to the actual ranges over time.

Comment: See also this chest data: https://www.reddit.com/r/Seaofthieves/comments/86firc/sea_of_thieves_value_sheet/